# Finding the inverse of an integer

Tags: java, math

I have a float between 0 and 1, which I'm using to create an integer between 0 and 255.  I can accomplish this through

```
integer = float * 255;
```

This works fine if I wanted 0 to be 0 and 1 to be 255, however I want it the exact opposite! I would like it if 1 could be 0 and 255 could be 1.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `(1.0f - yourFloat) * 255`?

Comment: for `i = 1` to become 0 and `i = 255` to become 1, you would need something like: `float f = (i - 1) * 1.0f / 254;`

Comment: Do you realise that if you have a uniform distribution of values between 0 and 1 then you will map that to a non-uniform integer distribution from 0 to 255? 255 will be under-represented.  It is more usual for the float range to exclude 1 and to multiply by 256.

Answer (score 5):

Simple math. The solution is to use:

> integer = 255 * (1-float)

So the higher the float is the lower the coefficient used to multiply 255 will be.